# 3 of a kind, 5 rolls, 6-sized dice

Tags: probability

I am reliably informed that the probability of getting 3 of a kind in 5 rolls of a 6-sized dice is approximately $0.1929$.

I'm assuming this excludes 4-of a kind and 5-of a kind but not full-house (3 of a kind plus two of a kind).

Trying to check this I reasoned: Given an initial value for the first roll, I need two of the same and 2 different values.

$1/6 * 1/6 * 5/6 * 5/6 = 0.01929...$

This value seems bizarrely similar to the correct answer but off by a factor of 10.

Could someone please explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You calculated the probability that the first three rolls are the same, but the last two rolls produce a different result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You calculated the probability that the first three rolls are the same, but the last two rolls produce a different result.  However, there are
$$\binom{5}{3} = 10$$
sequences in which exactly three of the five rolls yield the same value.  This is your missing factor of $10$.

Based on your description of the problem, you want to find the probability that exactly three of the rolls are the same.

1. Choose which of the six values appears three times.
2. Choose which three of the five rolls are the same.
3. Multiply by the probability that that value occurs three times.
4. Multiply by the probability that the remaining two rolls produce a different value than those three rolls.

$$\binom{6}{1}\binom{5}{3}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^3\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^2$$

Comment: The last two rolls can be two equal numbers and two different numbers. How does your binomial coefficient regard that?

Comment: @callculus Robin is allowing the other two rolls to be the same.  The case in which they are different (which I would consider three of a kind) is contained among those cases.

Comment: Im just asking since it is not clear to me. In my view you can order $xxxyz$ in more ways than $xxxyy$. And I don´t see how $xxxyz$  is incoperated.

Comment: @callculus In both cases, there are six ways to choose the value of $x$ and $\binom{5}{3}$ ways to choose the three positions where $x$ appears.  For sequences of the form $xxxyy$, there are five ways to choose the value of $y$.  For sequences of the form $xxxyz$, there are $\binom{5}{2}$ ways to choose the values of $y$ and $z$, where $y \neq z$, and $2!$ ways to arrange them in the remaining positions.  Thus, there are a total of $$\binom{6}{1}\binom{5}{3}\left[\binom{5}{1} + \binom{5}{2}2!\right] = \binom{6}{1}\binom{5}{3}\binom{5}{1}^2$$ favorable cases.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Great comment!